# How would I solve the following?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}1&-4\\ -6&-6\end{pmatrix}$$

Find $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $M^2 + c_1M +c_2I_2 = 0$, where $I_2$ is the identity $2 \times 2$ matrix.

The matrix above is $M$.

I got stuck after I merged the $c_1$ and $c_2$ into their respective matrices and calculated the square of $M$.

Comment: remember that two matrices are the same if and only if all of their respective matrices are the same. Now in this equation remember that $0$ on the right hand side represents the matrix with all $0$ entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$M^2=\begin{pmatrix}25&20\\30&60\end{pmatrix},$$you have$$M^2+c_1M+c_2\operatorname{Id}_2=\begin{pmatrix}25+c_1+c_2&20-4c_1\\30-6c_1&60-6c_1+c_2\end{pmatrix}.$$So, take $c_1=5$ and $c_2=-30$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:$M^2-(trM)M+(detM)I=0$

Answer (score 2):

$M^2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 25 & 20 \\
 30 & 60 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$M^2 + c_1M +c_2I_2 = 0$ becomes

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 25 & 20 \\
 30 & 60 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c_1 & -4 c_1 \\
 -6 c_1 & -6 c_1 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c_2 & 0 \\
 0 & c_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

that is

$\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 c_1+c_2+25=0 & 20-4 c_1=0 \\
 30-6 c_1=0 & -6 c_1+c_2+60=0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

from $20-4c_1=0$ we get $c_1=5$ and substituting both in $c_1+c_2+25=0$ and in $-6c_1+c_2+60=0$ we get $c_2=-30$

Solution is $c_1=5;\;c_2=-30$